# Pull commentdata for pre_comment_on_post from comment_post_ID

Tags: plugin-development

A method in a plugin uses `preprocess_comment` but that commentdata array does not have `comment_approved` because the comment hasn't been recorded. I'm trying to rewrite the method using `pre_comment_on_post` but noticing that the information returned is the `comment_post_ID`.

How can the `comment_post_ID` be used to grab the array of the commentdata only for the comment which is going to be written to WP?

I've tried `get_comments` but it pulls everything but the comment about to be written. Here is a snippet of code which shows the `var_dump` is the `comment_post_ID`.

```
public function hooks() {
    add_action( 'pre_comment_on_post', array( $this, 'write' ), 10, 1 );
}

public function write( $comment_post_ID ) {
    var_dump($comment_post_ID);
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to grab the comment and post it externally then have it written to WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preprocess_comment` inside `wp_new_comment()` filter to access/modify the data of the comment that is going to be written.

```

```
/**
 * Filters a comment's data before it is sanitized and inserted into the database.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param array $commentdata Comment data.
 */
$commentdata = apply_filters( 'preprocess_comment', $commentdata );
```

just make sure you hook after the plugin in question (using a greater priority) in order your filter to come afterwards whatever the plugin does to `$commentdata` or before it (using a lower filter priority) if you need to process `$commentdata` before it's passed to the plugin. See [add_filter's docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) if `$priority` argument is new to you.

Comment: Thank you but all the var dumps show that the `preprocess_comment` data does not have comment_approved. It is preprocessing before approval. I've rewritten the function to use `comment_post` and it works.